# If a Druid Provokes an AoO by Their Wild Shape, Who Takes the Damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, opportunity-attack, wild-shape

Inspired by this question: [Can a druid get out of wild shape to avoid an opportunity attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93876/can-a-druid-get-out-of-wild-shape-to-avoid-an-opportunity-attack)

In the cited question, the Druid wild shapes from a large creature back into a medium creature, placing themselves more than 5' from their opponent, thus provoking an OA.

By the OA rules,

> The attack interrupts the provoking creature's movement, occurring right before the creature leaves your reach.

The rules say this interrupts the movement, but it's not clear from the Wild Shape rules when the Druid is relying on the beast's hit points and their own hit point pool

If the OA connects, which pool of hit points is the damage taken from?

Comment: Now that the cited question has an accepted answer which runs contrary to the current frame of this question, is there anything you would like to add to this question to separate it from  the other question? As it stands, the answers you get here are going to be effectively duplicates of the accepted one there.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree with the accepted answer as it's written. I think a less popular answer is correct, specifically one that suggests it does provoke.

Comment: You might want to rephrase the focus of this question then. If you state that you will take it as a fact that you will allow an opportunity attack during the wild shape reversion, using a house rule if doing so isn't strictly RAW, we might be able to flesh out a good answer. Otherwise, most of the answers you will receive will be "it doesn't matter because the attack can't happen."

Answer (score 3):

### Forced movement doesn't provoke AoO.

PHB pg. 195 - Opportunity Attacks

> You also don’t provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction.

Comment: You might want to check the answers on the linked question; there is some debate about whether wild shape constitutes forced movement (for what it's worth I agree with you).

Comment: Wild shape says nothing about moving you, so no AoO is triggered, regardless of how people want to read it. Changing size isn't movement. The key word is, "when someone or something **moves** you."

Comment: Yep, I'm with you.  Wild shape doesn't move you, it only changes your size.