# Where does the water weird from a Weird Tank go when it emerges?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters, published-adventures, princes-of-the-apocalypse

I'm trying to figure out how the water weird from a *weird tank* emerges from the tank and how it should be represented on a standard grid.

The description of the [*weird tank*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/weird-tank) magic item (*Princes of the Apocalypse*, page 223) says:

> A water weird is contained within the tank. While wearing the tank, you can use an action to open it, allowing the water weird to emerge. The water weird acts immediately after you in the initiative order, and it is bound to the tank.

This part is pretty clear to me: the weird remains inside the tank until summoned, and the source of water for the weird is the water within the tank.

Therefore, the weird cannot leave the vicinity of the tank, per the [water weird](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/water-weird)'s Water Bound trait (*Monster Manual*, page 299):

> ***Water Bound***. The water weird dies if it leaves the water to which it is bound or if that water is destroyed.

All fine so far. To me, this means that the water weird *must* occupy the same space as the tank. Since the water weird cannot fly, this means that the owner must remove the tank and place it down on a space separate from themselves (to avoid drowning in it) and the weird would then occupy a 2x2 square with one square containing the tank. It shouldn't be able to move from this square unless another source of water is available.

Does that sound right?

Comment: Hi Kjata30, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] for the usual badge and check out the [help] for our site specific information. This is a great first question. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: Perhaps related: "[How does increasing in size affect adjacent squares and enemies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153413)"

Answer (score 6):

## The Water Weird is in the Weird Tank at all times.

Remember that the Weird Tank is a:

> ... ten-gallon tank of blown glass and sculpted bronze with a backpack-like carrying harness fashioned from tough leather.

As you correctly point out:

> ... it is bound to the tank.

It cannot leave the tank without the tank being destroyed.

The Water Weird can emerge from the tank after you use an action to open it.  It then remains in your space (as long as you are wearing the backpack).

It does not need to be placed down, or into another source of water, the Weird Tank is its source of water.

### The Water Weird can only drown a target it makes a melee weapon attack on, and constricts them.

The Water Weird can only drown a target it uses the Constrict action on.  If you were wearing the Weird Tank, and you got into this situation, you would presumably just telepathically command the Water Weird to retract instead of letting it drown you.

Comment: This doesn't really explain where the Water Weird goes or what space it occupies. Is the water weird sharing the space with the creature carrying the tank? Does it occupy adjacent squares? This is a good start but needs an [edit] to answer the whole question.

Comment: How do you propose I improve the, “it remains in your space (as long as you wear the backpack)” and the opening “The Water Weird is in the Weird Tank at all times” statements to make it more clear about which space the Water Weird is in?

Comment: Well the main thing is the the Water Weird is size Large, therefore takes up a 2x2 space on the grid. But the tank is likely being carried by a medium creature. How is that resolved? I think that was the main crux of the question.

Comment: Agreed, the Water Weird does not have any trait allowing it to occupy the Weird Tank bearer's space. By RAW, it *cannot* occupy the same space as the wielder. Presumably, it either "emerges" only enough to attack without leaving the tank, or it "emerges" to an adjacent space without leaving the tank... Attacking from within the tank seems less problematic; if being adjacent enough to touch a space, were enough to avoid leaving it, this would make a lot of boundaries\threshholds rather abstract. Surely, it either remains in the tank, or shares the bearer's space? The description is insufficient

Comment: Or perhaps the Water Weird is *supposed* to have the trait "***Amorphous Form.*** *The Water Weird can occupy another creature’s space and vice versa.*" & its omission is merely an oversight??? The question of where the Water Weird "emerges" to, without "leaving" the tank or occupying an already occupied space, seems obvious; a strange thing to overlook!