# What space do I occupy after Polymorphing into a bigger creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph

Let's say I cast Polymorph on myself to turn into a Giant Ape (Huge size). Would the 3x3 space I now occupy necessarily be centered on my previous position? Or can I grow in a different direction so that my previous square is now a border or a corner of the 3x3?
If I have to keep the same center, what about polymorphing into creatures that are Large or Gargantuan (and don't have a "center square")?

Moreover, let's say I am flying before I cast the spell. Would I grow up and down at the same time, and thus not fall the full distance? Or would I only grow upward?

Would all of this be the same if I was polymorphed against my will? Would I or the polymorpher choose the new occupied space? (assuming there is a choice to make)

Comment: Related: [How does increasing in size affect adjacent squares and enemies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153413/23547), [What happens when Wild Shape/Polymorph runs out in a space that's too small?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67501/23547), [What happens when you end up sharing an enemy (or friend's) space due to a size change?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107469/23547)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The rules don’t cover this. The DM decides.

The rules don’t answer this question. The DM must decide. Situations where it matters are rare, but the times it has actually mattered, I try to make a ruling that is neutral or advantageous to the players. I don’t want the fun of casting *polymorph* to be diminished by some terribly inconvenient choice of space occupation.

Comment: I agree with this. I feel like if you no longer occupy the same dimensions as a result of using your action, part of that action probably included growing/shrinking into your new space of choice. I've never been at a table that didn't run it that way - it provides a slight mobility advantage at times but it's niche and not game breaking unless you're a level 20 druid with infinite wildshape... which by comparison is much more concerning than which square of space you do/don't occupy this round, IMO.

Comment: @TheFallen0ne I cannot count how many times the druid has trivialized an encounter by  polymorphing  into  giraffe, biting the top of a tree, then turning back into human

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a rule on this, but with some common sense and an impartial ruling a fair settlement can be reached.

It makes sense that the growth incurred as a result of *polymorph*, *enlarge* person and similar effects is an outward emanation centered on the target; it only would grow in one direction, up, due to the resistance/pushback of the ground; in the sky it would grow in all directions evenly.  This would reduce the distance to the ground by half of the vertical size increase, although the distance from the **center** of the character to the ground remains unchanged.

The growth horizontally expands into the closest unoccupied space; if no such space exists then it tries to force its way into an occupied/obstructed space.  If multiple directions are available, it's easy enough to let the dice decide.  A player could then feel a minor victory when the dice rolls favorably, or lend for some hilarious mishaps that result in a good story in hindsight.